# Understanding the differences between pdf and postscript format and the link between this format and LateX/TeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf, postscript, ps

I am trying to understand how pdf and ps format works.

At first I used to think that ps was a format used by printer which contains detailed printing instructions. That was the reason why this ps files were so heavy.

But it appear that this is much more complicated than that. ps is a Turing-complete language. Read sequentially to generate page rendering.

But when I look into what pdf is, I find almost the same description.

So my questions are (some of them might have a similar answer):

- What are the big differences between pdf and ps ? Is pdf just a newer/more modern version of ps ?
- why pdf and ps has such different file size for the same output ?
- If pdf is just a text description why can't I open it with a text editor ? Is it compressed with gzip or something to reduce size ?
- When I write LaTeX code and create a pdf with a compiler, is the compiler first create a ps file then a pdf, or is this two file formats completely independent ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Only the last bullet point is really on-topic for us (although many people here know a lot about the other points)

Comment: you can create uncompressed pdf if you start with `\RequirePackage{expl3}\ExplSyntaxOn\pdf_uncompress:\ExplSyntaxOff`.  The last point depends on how you compile. pdflatex will create directly pdf, latex+dvips+ps2pdf goes through ps.

Comment: .pdf is a compressed version of postscript.

Comment: @Bernard no not really. There are quite some differences. Check the pdf reference, it has a section about the differences.